# what is the equation of a rotated ellipsoid?

Tags: rotations, elliptic-equations

I used this equation for rotated 2D ellipse:

$$\frac{(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)^2}{a^2} +\frac{(x\sin\theta-y\cos\theta)^2}{b^2} =1$$

$a$, $b$ are major-axis and minor-axes length of the ellipse and $\theta$ is the rotation angle.

what is this kind of equation for the rotated ellipsoid in 3D?
we have $a$, $b$ and $c$ that are 3 axes length of ellipsoid and $\theta , \phi$ which are rotation angle in horizontal plane and vertical plane respectively. Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Are you having trouble working out the net rotation or the resulting implicit equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of unrotated the ellipsoid in 3D is $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$
Write the rotation matrices (you can look it up on wikipedia). You have $(x',y',z')^T=R(\theta,\phi)\cdot(x,y,z)^T$ This yield each of $x',y',z'$ as linear combinations of $x,y,z$. Now just plug in $x',y',z'$ instead of $x,y,z$ in the first equation, and you are done.

Comment: Thank you very much. but unfortunately I could not find the rotation matrix `R(θ,ϕ)`?

Comment: There are two rotations. You need to know the order (I do not know what convention you use). Do you rotate first around the $x$ axis? or $y$? or $z$? Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations, the two matrices that correspond to your convention, and multiply them

Comment: Thanks. Should I use `R = Rz(θ).Rx(ϕ)` ?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. It means that you are rotating first around the $x$ axis, then everything around $z$

Comment: Thank you for your help.